# unwrapping object for passing as function arguments

Tags: function, typescript, types, parameter-passing

If we have a function like this:

```
function foo(param1: string, param2: number);
```

and an object like this:

```
let obj = {param1: 'blah', param2; 10}
```

How can I directly unwrap the object to pass its data to the function arguments?
Something like this:

```
foo(...obj)
```

Comment: You can try like this foo(...obj: any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Titian Cernicova Dragomir's answer.

I couldn't find any convention of doing this.

What you can do (as it is also suggested by @Titian Cernicova Dragomir) is :

```
let obj = {param1: 'blah', param2; 10}
function foo({param1: string, param2: number}){}

foo(obj);
```

or you can also make manual deconstruction

```
let obj = {param1: 'blah', param2; 10}
function foo({param1: string, param2: number}){}


let {param1, param2} = obj;
foo(obj);
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely the way to go if foo can be changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.values` to get the values of an object. The problem is that the order is not necessarily guaranteed and so this would be extremely error prone since order matters usually in function parameters:

```
Object.values({param1: 'blah', param2: 10}) // ["blah", 10]

Object.values({param2: 10, param1: 'blah'}) // [10, "blah"]
```

So for example in JS this would work:

```
function foo(param1: string, param2: string) { console.log(param1, param2)}

let obj = { param1: 'blah', param2: "10" }
foo(...Object.values(obj));
```

TS does not allow the above because it can't be sure that what `values` returned will have two items, so the only place this would be allowed and advisable is if you have a rest parameter:

```
declare function foo(...param1: string[]): void;

let obj = { param1: 'blah', param2: "10" }
foo(...Object.values(obj));
```

You can create a function to extract the object values into a tuple and spread that to the values, but at that point you are probably better off  ust using regular syntax. I present this version below mostly for some fun with tuple types :

```
declare function foo<T>(param1: string, param2: number): void;
function args<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(o: T, ...keys:K) : { [P in keyof K]: K[P] extends keyof T ? T[K[P]]: never} {
    let r : any[] = []
    for (const key of keys) {
      r.push(o[key]);
    }
    return r as any;
}

let obj = { param1: 'blah', param2: 10 }
foo(...args(obj, 'param1', 'param2'));
```

**NOTE** The better solution is to change `foo` to take in an object instead of separate params.